# Fix with discord.js music bot, stops playing the music before the song is actually over, tried everything

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

discord.js 12v

The bot works right, the only problem is that it stops playing, in most of the songs, at the last third part of it, without leaving any error message in the console.

I've seen that the main problem to this is within the FFMPEG executable getting corrupt packets from the webhost, which causes it to terminate. I saw another post saying that adding this lines:

`'reconnect', '1', 'reconnect_streamed', '1', 'reconnect_delay_max', '4'`

to the FFMPEG_ARGUEMENTS array in `npm-modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/player/BasePlayer.js` should solve the problem, if not, then changing `ytdl-core` to `ytdl-core-discord`. I've already done this, and the music stills stopping.

This is my code for the `play` command:

```
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core-discord");
const ytSearch = require("yt-search");

const queue = new Map();

module.exports = {
    name: "play",
    aliases: ["skip", "stop"],
    description: "Walter pone musica",
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord){

        const voice_channel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if(!voice_channel) return message.channel.send("No estas en ningun canal, genio.")
        const permissions = voice_channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if(!permissions.has("CONNECT")) return message.channel.send("No tienes los permisos para eso pa, pide que te los den.");
        if(!permissions.has("SPEAK")) return message.channel.send("No tienes los permisos para eso pa, pide que te los den.");

        const server_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

        if(cmd === "play"){

            if (!args.length) return message.channel.send("Pero dime una cancion, animal.");
            let song = {};

            if(ytdl.validateURL(args[0])){
                const song_info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
                song = {title: song_info.videoDetails.title, url: song_info.videoDetails.video_url};
            }else{

                const video_finder = async (query) => {
                    const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
                    return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
                }

                const video = await video_finder(args.join(" "));

                if(video){
                    song = {title: video.title, url: video.url};
                }else{
                    message.channel.send("No encontre nada al respecto");
                }
            }

            if(!server_queue){

                const queue_constructor = {
                    voice_channel: voice_channel,
                    text_channel: message.channel,
                    connection: null,
                    songs: []
                }

                queue.set(message.guild.id, queue_constructor);
                queue_constructor.songs.push(song);

                try{
                    queue_constructor.connection = await voice_channel.join();
                    video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);
                }
                catch(error){
                    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                    message.channel.send("Hubo pedos para conectarse al canal de voz, perdon banda");
                    throw error;
                }
            }else{
                server_queue.songs.push(song);
                return message.channel.send(`***${song.title}*** añadido a tu cola`);
            }
        }
    }
}

const video_player = async (guild, song) => {
    const song_queue = queue.get(guild.id);

    if(!song){

        song_queue.voice_channel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }

    const stream = await ytdl(song.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
    song_queue.connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1, type: "opus"})
        .on("finish", () => {
            song_queue.songs.shift();
            video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
        });
    await song_queue.text_channel.send(`Me ando tocando ***${song.title}***`);
}
```

My FFMPEG_ARGUEMENTS arrays is like this:

```
const FFMPEG_ARGUMENTS = ['-reconnect', '1', '-reconnect_streamed', '1', '-reconnect_delay_max', '4', '-analyzeduration', '0', '-loglevel', '0', '-f', 's16le', '-ar', '48000', '-ac', '2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will delay stopping the song by 2 seconds

```js
song_queue.connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1, type: "opus"})
        .on("finish", async () => {
            let t = await (new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{setTimeout(resolve, 2000)}))
            song_queue.songs.shift();
            video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
        });
```

Comment: thanks, but the "finish" event isn't even reached, because of the music randomly stopping

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it can be a bug of previous versions of discordjs/voice.
Try updating the package!

```
npm i @discordjs/voice@latest
```

See this:

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/9185

Comment: link to bug ticket?